# Two libraries have same values.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-gradle-plugin, libraries, build-dependencies

I am making an Andoird app in which I have used many dependencies and I need all the dependencies.but an error has encountered stating that `rippleColor` has already been defined.

I have searched on the internet all I have found is that my dependencies have same name in values.xml.

Error1:-

> Attribute "rippleColor" has already been defined

Error2:-

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\RANJEET JAIN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ranjeet.example.com.finance"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.2'
compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
}
```

Comment: when `rippleColor` became an attribute used by the support library, most library that were using it were updated. Identify which library uses that attribute. See if there is an update. Otherwise, change library, or modify it and recompile it yourself.

Comment: when i try to modify it says "Generated sorce file should no be edited.The changes will be lost when sources are generated".